# Angular 9 how to bypass particular route in the guard?

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular9

I have a guard that redirects the user to `tabs` page if user has been authenticated else redirects to `home`(login) page.

Now on a particular operation, my backend express server redirects the user to `order-success` page. But logic in the guard doesn't allow the user to be redirected to `order-success` page instead user gets redirected to `tabs` page

So how to bypass this url in the guard so that user will go to `order-success` page

Thank you in advance

auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate   {
  
  constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService, public router : Router,) {}

  async canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {

    let auth = await this.auth.isAuthenticated() // returns true if user is authenticated else false
    if(auth) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['home'])
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'tabs', pathMatch: 'full' },

{
    path: 'tabs', canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabbar/tabbar.module').then( m => m.TabbarPageModule)
  },

  {
    path: 'order-success',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/order-success/order-success.module').then(m => m.OrderSuccessPageModule)
  },
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand your problem completely but you need to use `canLoad` guard for lazy modules.

Comment: Let me explain. I have a guard that redirects user to tabs page if user is authenticated else redirect to home(login) page. Now my backend server on successful payments, redirects user to order-success page. But user gets redirected to tabs page due to guard. I want user to be redirected to order-success page.

Comment: Can you please check the example `Stackblitz`  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-46vb6u ? If your backend is navigating you directly, you need to set your auth state at `App Initializer` beucase the auth state must be filled, before the `Guard` works.

Comment: I tried this. Calling auth state at App Initializer but not working. When server redirects, the user goes to tabs due to guard

Comment: I can help, if you can create a `Stackblitz` example for us.

Comment: Please find https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93nywr I made a quick one.

Comment: You can use websockets to go around the ./ inbound url problem.

Comment: Okay. Let me try